# How not to run specific cucumber scenario when some flag is set

Tags: java, testing, cucumber

The problem is I got two diferent realisations of the mechanism I'm working on, and i got tests for both of them in one feature file. In the program I am choosing which mechanism to use, using a simple flag stored in properties file.

---

I wonder if I somehow can check if the flag is true or false and depending on the answer include or exclude a particular scenario

Answer (score 0):

Throw a Skipped/Pending exception. This will cancel the scenario from being ran.

A similar mechanism exists in Ruby, but there is a helper method that does this for you called `skip_this_scenario`

Comment: What are skipped/pending exceptions? I can't find them in the JDK docs.

Comment: How do I use `skip_this_scenario` in Java? ;)